# android-wear embedding old (cached) wear apk in the mobile-release apk

Tags: android, android-studio, packaging, wear-os

I am generating the signed apk using the option Build -> Generate Signed APK

Problem is mobile-release.apk doesn't embed the updated wear apk. I have tried changing text / logic, but it always display the old thing.

I have tried all of the following, any ideas why it keep embedding the old wear apk instead of creating the new one.

- File -> Invalidate cache / Restart.
- Build -> Clean + Rebuild project
- Clear cache of wear app on phone
- Settings -> Resync all apps (option on handheld wear app)
- manually delete all apks in the build folder of both mobile and wear mobile.

Any hints, or anybody facing similar issue, please reply.

**Update 1:**

I tested the generated *wear-release.apk* separately, its the latest, still somehow the embedded apk is old.

I changed my gradle config to manually include newly generated apk,

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// wearApp project(':wear')
wearApp files('wear-release11.apk') // renamed purposefully to make sure its picking right file.
```

it indeed give error if **wear-release11.apk** is missing.. but when the **wear-release11.apk** is available, **it still embed some old cached apk.**

**Update 2:**
I extracted and inspected the contents of generated APK, it indeed has the latest generated apk inside it. But somehow, the phone push cached version. Not sure if its 'android-wear' companion app or the Play Store app causing this bug. 
For me uninstalling the android-wear companion app (surprisingly, not just clearing data) solve this issue. But it will cache the apk again after some time.

Comment: Impossible to tell because it should work. Does the wear-debug.apk look fine? The gradle line `wearApp project(':wearablemodule')` is what embeds the wearable into the mobile-release apk, so start debugging from there.

Comment: Everything else, including the generated wear.apk (thats generated in parallel) is fine. Still it embeds some cached version. And i verified it by unzipping the apk.. the embedded version is older!

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the previous version first?  Or is that not feasible?

Comment: I am finding this too. Not sure what is going on - everything was fine a week ago. maybe a new version of Android Studio? I'm on 0.8.9

Comment: Although saying that, the embedded APK does have the updated version number in manifest that I put in to test.  So perhaps my phone is the thing caching the old version of APK and copying it to  the watch? What did you find out @Umair ?

Comment: @barkside  Yes, its not android studio.. i tried to extract the contents of generated apk, in infact have the new apk.. but phone push the cached one. So far i didn't find any solution.. though for me it only give error when i try to side load the application.. when i download my app from playstore, it looks fine. 
For me, uninstalling the android-wear app from phone fix the issue (surprisingly not just clearing the data!). Not sure its the android-wear app or Play Store app which is responsible for this bug.

Comment: @barkside, in our company 2 people work on android wear and we both face the issue, so my guess is that it should be a common problem. But I m not getting much info about it on internet. May be its something specific to samsung? .. are you using Samsung phone?
as in our case we both used Samsung (note 3 and S4) and the watch we used was LG G Watch.

Comment: @Umair So I also found that it could be side-loading issue. Perhaps with "adb install -r". Doing adb push, then install from ES File Browser seemed to work fine. Pairing watch with a difference phone worked too. The HTC One S failed for me - not Samsung.  Now I have issues with repairing watch back with HTC! Nothing is easy!

Comment: @barkside its older comment.. but for me, just turning off one phone's bluetooth help to pair the watch with other. Otherwise you can always reset the watch, Settings->Reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen a situation a while ago where the wearable app would get stuck and would not update. I think the bug has been resolved, but I wanted to put this answer down for the record just in case it is still happening.

If you are 100% sure your APK is versioned properly, then you can try this procedure which should always fix it up. If this does not fix it, then there is a problem with your APK build process:

1. Factory reset the watch: Settings ... Reset device
2. On your phone: Settings ... Apps ... Google Play services
3. Click on clear cache
4. Click on manage space
5. Manage wearable storage ... Clear now
6. Under total data used by Google Play services ... Clear all data
7. Reboot the phone
8. Try to pair the phone with the watch again﻿

Comment: also my problem is.. how it will affect the production application? if our users will have older wear app but newer handheld app!!

Comment: What kind of phone are you on? The steps above work on my Nexus 5.

Comment: This should not affect your production application. This bug should have been fixed a while ago, and clearing this will fix up the problem if it occurred before. You should not have to do the above steps normally.

Comment: Thanks Wayne Piekarski.. accepted your answer, added additional info.

Comment: Just got the same error on the latest companion app ver. 1.1.1.1901499. After that I manually uninstalled the wear app from the watch and installed android_wear_micro_apk.apk from resources of the main apk and it works fine.

Comment: Manage storage will be under play store settings: Settings->Application Manager ->Google Player Services. Under Storage block, can see Manage Storage.

Comment: I am facing this issue. Signed apk is installing wear apk in Moto 360 successfully, but not installing in Moto 360 2nd Gen. Why?

Comment: @UmangKothari use adb logcat and search for WearablePkgInstaller on the phone or wearable, there will be an error message telling you what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks you sir @WaynePiekarski