# Watch face uninstalled by WearablePkgInstaller after a reboot

Tags: android, wear-os

I am facing a problem with one of my watch face "fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery".

When I install it on a wear device or on emulator, nothing goes wrong and it works fine.

Then I reboot the wear device or the emulator. It restarts on my watch face as expected, but some seconds after, the screens turns black, and it falls back on the default android watch face "simple".

In the logs, I am getting the following :

```
04-20 11:26:43.801    3013-3041/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller W/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Version number of new app (0) is equal to existing app for com.google.android.apps.maps
04-20 11:26:43.805      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.715ms
04-20 11:26:43.842    1919-2913/com.google.android.wearable.app D/WearablePackageInfoProvider﹕ 3013 is a system app.
04-20 11:26:43.952    3013-3041/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller I/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Sent installation request for com.google.android.apps.maps
04-20 11:26:43.990    1919-1945/com.google.android.wearable.app D/WearablePackageInfoProvider﹕ 3013 is a system app.
04-20 11:26:44.337      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 29.792ms
04-20 11:26:44.807      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.394ms
04-20 11:26:45.476      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 105.178ms
04-20 11:26:45.523      350-362/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 49.255ms
04-20 11:26:45.622      350-362/system_process I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17258(692KB) AllocSpace objects, 11(1453KB) LOS objects, 19% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 52.684ms total 635.886ms
04-20 11:26:45.631      350-361/system_process I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 572.338ms for cause HeapTrim
04-20 11:26:46.050    1949-1949/fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 11:26:46.383      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 65.046ms
04-20 11:26:48.444    3013-3041/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller W/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Version number of new app (1401) is equal to existing app for com.google.android.music
04-20 11:26:48.548    1919-1948/com.google.android.wearable.app D/WearablePackageInfoProvider﹕ 3013 is a system app.
04-20 11:26:48.975    3013-3041/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller I/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Sent installation request for com.google.android.music
04-20 11:26:49.085    3013-3041/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller I/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Sent delete request for fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery
04-20 11:26:49.089      350-997/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Package doesn't exist in get block uninstall fr.thema.wear.watch.glowingtron
04-20 11:26:49.090    3013-3041/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller I/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Sent delete request for fr.thema.wear.watch.glowingtron
04-20 11:26:49.124    1919-2447/com.google.android.wearable.app D/WearablePackageInfoProvider﹕ 3013 is a system app.
04-20 11:26:49.328      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 20.445ms
04-20 11:26:49.648      350-362/system_process I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 26253(917KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(464KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 8MB/9MB, paused 2.719ms total 213.076ms
04-20 11:26:50.357      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 29.915ms
04-20 11:26:50.625      350-426/system_process D/PackageManager﹕ Renaming /data/app/vmdl250365332.tmp to /data/app/com.google.android.apps.fitness-1
04-20 11:26:50.659      350-426/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ New package has a different signature: com.google.android.apps.fitness
04-20 11:26:50.727      350-386/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery appid=10038 user=-1: uninstall pkg
04-20 11:26:50.729      350-386/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 1949:fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery/u0a38 (adj 1): stop fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery
04-20 11:26:50.759     350-2672/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{34900f38 u0 fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery.WatchFaceService}
04-20 11:26:50.781      350-350/system_process W/WallpaperManagerService﹕ Wallpaper service gone: ComponentInfo{fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery/fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery.WatchFaceService}
04-20 11:26:50.827      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 18.019ms
04-20 11:26:50.853      350-386/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery/.WatchFaceService in 1000ms
04-20 11:26:50.877      350-386/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping service ServiceRecord{2fb89f01 u0 fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery/.WatchFaceService}
04-20 11:26:50.951     350-2179/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Spurious death for ProcessRecord{2a3fc305 1949:fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery/u0a38}, curProc for 1949: null
04-20 11:26:51.024      350-405/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 11:26:51.148      350-405/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 11:26:51.218      350-405/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 11:26:51.278      350-405/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 11:26:51.376      350-405/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 11:26:51.455      350-405/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 11:26:51.827      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 15.446ms
04-20 11:26:52.035      350-426/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery appid=10038 user=0: pkg removed
04-20 11:26:52.159     350-1049/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
04-20 11:26:52.569      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 256.793ms
04-20 11:26:52.624      350-350/system_process D/JobSchedulerService﹕ Receieved: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
04-20 11:26:52.659    1919-1919/com.google.android.wearable.app I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8554(574KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(501KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 1.676ms total 571.570ms
04-20 11:26:52.790      350-383/system_process W/Searchables﹕ No global search activity found
04-20 11:26:52.918      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 104.949ms
04-20 11:26:52.957      350-362/system_process I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49001(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 7(338KB) LOS objects, 19% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 17.728ms total 706.074ms
04-20 11:26:53.187    2099-2819/com.google.process.gapps I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 6.850ms for cause DisableMovingGc
04-20 11:26:53.499      350-383/system_process W/WallpaperManagerService﹕ Wallpaper uninstalled, removing: ComponentInfo{fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery/fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery.WatchFaceService}
04-20 11:26:53.715    1919-1941/com.google.android.wearable.app I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2023(241KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(48KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 3MB/3MB, paused 2.063ms total 276.771ms
04-20 11:26:54.007    1919-1941/com.google.android.wearable.app I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2065(191KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 3MB/4MB, paused 1.844ms total 274.264ms
04-20 11:26:54.443      350-357/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 616.049ms
04-20 11:26:54.547      350-426/system_process W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10.861ms
04-20 11:26:54.761    1919-1919/com.google.android.wearable.app W/ClockworkHome.HomeView﹕ Watch face removed
```

It seems that the watch face is uninstalled due to a conflict with android.music.

```
04-20 11:26:48.444    3013-3041/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller W/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Version number of new app (1401) is equal to existing app for com.google.android.music
04-20 11:26:48.548    1919-1948/com.google.android.wearable.app D/WearablePackageInfoProvider﹕ 3013 is a system app.
04-20 11:26:48.975    3013-3041/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller I/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Sent installation request for com.google.android.music
04-20 11:26:49.085    3013-3041/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller I/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Sent delete request for fr.thema.wear.watch.eyeonbattery
```

Am I right?
Is there a solution to this issue? I did not found out what was the problem in the first place :(

Comment: Can you show us the package names and version information from the build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml files? Also, does this problem happen when you compile the standard WatchFace sample or just your own custom version?

Comment: Hi Wayne Piekarski, You helped me with another answer you made on an other thread (see below). 
The bug seems to occur on Android 4.3. May be the fix you are talking about was released in a later version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that after installing the release apk on the phone, the embedded wear apk deployed on wear device was an older version (features missing, pretty weird).

By searching on internet, I found an other thread (in which you participated in) from a dev experiencing the same problem of older version deployed.

[android-wear embedding old (cached) wear apk in the mobile-release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772847/android-wear-embedding-old-cached-wear-apk-in-the-mobile-release-apk)

I followed your procedure, and it solved the problem of older version. And the problem of watch face uninstalled also.

I think that the wear device does these delete of watch face when this problem of version occurs.
So it seems to be an issue of the "Google Play Service". I hope it will not happen to often.

Thanks a lot Wayne Piekarski for your answer on this thread and the other one, It was very helpful