# Android Wear app does not reflect new changes in signed APK

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working with Wearable application which is already on Google Play Store.Now I want to update this app with new features.

**Issue:** Android Wear app does not reflect new changes in Signed APK

**Devices used for testing:**

1. Phone - Nexus 5, Nexus 4, Samsung Galaxy s4
2. Watch - LG G Watch, Android Emulator

**Following steps are performed,**

1. Generate signed APK of application, It will create two APKs,

   a. app-release.apk

   b. wearable-release.apk
2. When I install app-release.apk, it installs on both devices but wearable app does not reflect new changes. Yes, Wear app shows old app's features only.

   But when I directly installed wearable-release.apk in watch then it shows new features. And I have also installed res/raw/android_wear_micro_apk which is inside app-release.apk, It also shows new features.

I have performed same steps in other Android wear app before three months but at that it is working with charm. Now I am facing above issue.

So, Is there any thing related to Google's Android Wear app? like, Android Wear stores Wear apk somewhere and next time when application is updated, it will install older apk rather than new one.

Is there anything that I am missing? Please provide solution for it.

**Mobile app log**

```
    08-21 11:54:58.013      585-614/? I/PackageManager﹕ Running dexopt on: com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:54:58.043  11363-11363/? I/dex2oat﹕ dex2oat: /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.spec.smartwear-1.apk@classes.dex
08-21 11:55:14.941      585-606/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.spec.smartwear appid=11758 user=-1: update pkg
08-21 11:55:16.592      585-585/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.spec.smartwear flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
08-21 11:55:17.073   1138-11639/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:55:17.093    1138-1138/? I/ConfigFetchService﹕ onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.spec.smartwear cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
08-21 11:55:17.133    1138-1138/? D/Vision﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.spec.smartwear flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.vision.DependencyBroadcastReceiverProxy (has extras) }
08-21 11:55:17.173   1515-11646/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi﹕ Updating corpora: APPS=com.spec.smartwear, CONTACTS=MAYBE
08-21 11:55:17.864   1454-11688/? I/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Setting DataItem to install wearable apps for com.spec.smartwear
```

**Wear app log**

```
08-21 11:51:46.995    1230-1408/? I/PackageManager? Package doesn't exist in get block uninstall com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:51:46.996    1230-1260/? W/PackageManager? Package named 'com.spec.smartwear' doesn't exist.
08-21 11:51:47.025    1925-1925/? E/Pm? Failure details: Bundle[{android.content.pm.extra.STATUS=1, android.content.pm.extra.PACKAGE_NAME=com.spec.smartwear, android.content.pm.extra.LEGACY_STATUS=-1, android.content.pm.extra.STATUS_MESSAGE=DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR}]
08-21 11:52:46.108    1502-1951/? W/datatransport? handleSetDataItem: got an old sequence id, node=d53bfd3a, peer=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, wear://ffa8bd88-0f2e-46e4-aead-e76984fe620f/package_manager/package/com.spec.smartwear, sourceNode=f1549079, seqId=2253, maxSeqId=3620
08-21 11:52:46.639    1502-1951/? W/datatransport? handleSetDataItem: got an old sequence id, node=d53bfd3a, peer=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, wear://f1549079/package_info/com.spec.smartwear, sourceNode=f1549079, seqId=3614, maxSeqId=3620
08-21 11:53:02.405    1502-1951/? W/datatransport? handleSetDataItem: got an old sequence id, node=d53bfd3a, peer=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, wear://1fff4ec7-af29-4d64-ba52-a9ae5890004d/capabilities/com.spec.smartwear/5e9ad63faa2b487e45693c099f5e37621e1d20fd/smart_wear, sourceNode=8832f508, seqId=17544, maxSeqId=39833
08-21 11:53:04.931    1502-1951/? W/datatransport? handleSetDataItem: got an old sequence id, node=d53bfd3a, peer=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, wear://2ab8ffdf-467e-4b74-9eca-b1a8623f484e/package_manager/package/com.spec.smartwear, sourceNode=8832f508, seqId=29867, maxSeqId=39833
08-21 11:53:10.253    1502-1951/? W/datatransport? handleSetDataItem: got an old sequence id, node=d53bfd3a, peer=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, wear://2e6f7fc6-8118-4a91-a885-2efe29845586/capabilities/com.spec.smartwear/5e9ad63faa2b487e45693c099f5e37621e1d20fd/smart_wear, sourceNode=8832f508, seqId=30324, maxSeqId=39833
08-21 11:53:13.097    1502-1951/? W/datatransport? handleSetDataItem: got an old sequence id, node=d53bfd3a, peer=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, wear://1fff4ec7-af29-4d64-ba52-a9ae5890004d/package_manager/package/com.spec.smartwear, sourceNode=8832f508, seqId=37925, maxSeqId=39833
08-21 11:53:14.883    1502-1951/? W/datatransport? handleSetDataItem: got an old sequence id, node=d53bfd3a, peer=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, wear://ffa8bd88-0f2e-46e4-aead-e76984fe620f/capabilities/com.spec.smartwear/6d9f4cab0ab7681de1caff4d83920cd252ddec3c/smart_wear, sourceNode=8832f508, seqId=38842, maxSeqId=39833
08-21 11:53:15.112    1502-1951/? W/datatransport? handleSetDataItem: got an old sequence id, node=d53bfd3a, peer=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, wear://8832f508/package_info/com.spec.smartwear, sourceNode=8832f508, seqId=39817, maxSeqId=39833
08-21 11:53:30.819    1428-1581/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Sending install intent to PackageInstaller Intent { act=com.google.android.clockwork.packagemanager.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=content://com.google.android.clockwork.home.provider/host/com.spec.smartwear/wearable/com.spec.smartwear/apk typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/wearable_apk pkg=com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller (has extras) } forcom.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:53:30.826    1502-1951/? W/datatransport? handleSetDataItem: got an old sequence id, node=d53bfd3a, peer=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, wear://c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17/package_manager/package/com.spec.smartwear, sourceNode=c7e2844b-baca-4a13-9198-3de09fd1cb17, seqId=271117, maxSeqId=271118
08-21 11:53:32.700    1996-2097/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Sent installation request for com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:53:37.524    2013-2030/? D/DefContainer? Copying /data/data/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller/files/tmp/com.spec.smartwear.apk to base.apk
08-21 11:53:38.749    1230-1260/? D/PackageManager? Renaming /data/app/vmdl1193230775.tmp to /data/app/com.spec.smartwear-1
08-21 11:53:38.859    1230-1260/? I/PackageManager? Running dexopt on: /data/app/com.spec.smartwear-1/base.apk pkg=com.spec.smartwear isa=x86 vmSafeMode=false
08-21 11:53:38.873    2114-2114/? I/dex2oat? /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=6 --zip-location=/data/app/com.spec.smartwear-1/base.apk --oat-fd=7 --oat-location=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.spec.smartwear-1@base.apk@classes.dex --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --swap-fd=10
08-21 11:53:41.360    1428-1581/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Sending install intent to PackageInstaller Intent { act=com.google.android.clockwork.packagemanager.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=content://com.google.android.clockwork.home.provider/host/com.spec.smartwear/wearable/com.spec.smartwear/apk typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/wearable_apk pkg=com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller (has extras) } forcom.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:53:37.732    1996-2097/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Sent installation request for com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:53:58.138    1230-1230/? D/ZenLog? disable_effects: 0|com.google.android.wearable.app|0|packagemanager_notif-com.spec.smartwear|10003,listenerHints
08-21 11:53:58.726    1609-2152/? D/PkgBcastWearSrvc? Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:53:59.373    1996-2153/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Package com.spec.smartwear was installed.
08-21 11:53:59.900    2013-2026/? D/DefContainer? Copying /data/data/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller/files/tmp/com.spec.smartwear.apk to base.apk
08-21 11:54:00.401    1230-1260/? D/PackageManager? Renaming /data/app/vmdl1942995049.tmp to /data/app/com.spec.smartwear-2
08-21 11:54:00.405    1230-1260/? W/PackageManager? Attempt to re-install com.spec.smartwear without first uninstalling.
08-21 11:54:00.952    1609-1609/? I/ConfigFetchService? onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.spec.smartwear cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
08-21 11:54:15.770    1996-2158/? E/WearablePkgInstaller? Package install failed com.spec.smartwear, returnCode -1
08-21 11:54:40.446    1428-1581/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Sending uninstall intent to PackageInstaller Intent { act=com.google.android.clockwork.packagemanager.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE pkg=com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller (has extras) } for com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:54:40.448    1996-2097/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Sent delete request for com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:55:04.887    1230-1250/? I/ActivityManager? Force stopping com.spec.smartwear appid=10022 user=-1: uninstall pkg
08-21 11:55:04.944    1230-1260/? I/ActivityManager? Force stopping com.spec.smartwear appid=10022 user=0: pkg removed
08-21 11:55:06.167    1749-2197/? D/VoicemailCleanupService? Cleaning up data for package: com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:55:06.578    1996-2010/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Package com.spec.smartwear was uninstalled.
08-21 11:55:06.633    1609-2199/? D/PkgBcastWearSrvc? Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:55:06.830    1609-1609/? I/ConfigFetchService? onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.spec.smartwear cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
08-21 11:55:36.974    1428-1581/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Sending install intent to PackageInstaller Intent { act=com.google.android.clockwork.packagemanager.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=content://com.google.android.clockwork.home.provider/host/com.spec.smartwear/wearable/com.spec.smartwear/apk typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/wearable_apk pkg=com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller (has extras) } forcom.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:55:37.213    1996-2223/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Sent installation request for com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:56:00.099    2013-2031/? D/DefContainer? Copying /data/data/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller/files/tmp/com.spec.smartwear.apk to base.apk
08-21 11:56:07.314    1230-1260/? D/PackageManager? Renaming /data/app/vmdl1254173745.tmp to /data/app/com.spec.smartwear-1
08-21 11:56:07.334    1230-1260/? I/PackageManager? Running dexopt on: /data/app/com.spec.smartwear-1/base.apk pkg=com.spec.smartwear isa=x86 vmSafeMode=false
08-21 11:56:07.393    2256-2256/? I/dex2oat? /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=6 --zip-location=/data/app/com.spec.smartwear-1/base.apk --oat-fd=7 --oat-location=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.spec.smartwear-1@base.apk@classes.dex --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --swap-fd=10
08-21 11:56:16.698    1996-2158/? I/WearablePkgInstaller? Package com.spec.smartwear was installed.
08-21 11:56:17.346    1230-1230/? D/ZenLog? disable_effects: 0|com.google.android.wearable.app|0|packagemanager_notif-com.spec.smartwear|10003,listenerHints
08-21 11:56:17.692    1609-2284/? D/PkgBcastWearSrvc? Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.spec.smartwear
08-21 11:56:17.696    1609-1609/? I/ConfigFetchService? onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.spec.smartwear cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
08-21 11:57:47.717    1428-1428/? W/PackageManager? Failure retrieving resources for com.spec.smartwear: Resource ID #0x0
08-21 11:57:50.655    1230-1540/? I/ActivityManager? START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.spec.smartwear/.view.MainActivity} from uid 10003 on display 0
08-21 11:57:50.672    1230-1540/? V/WindowManager? addAppToken: AppWindowToken{ed6b0f2 token=Token{67b9bfd ActivityRecord{33427054 u0 com.spec.smartwear/.view.MainActivity t4}}} to stack=1 task=4 at 0
08-21 11:57:50.768    1230-1245/? I/ActivityManager? Start proc 2298:com.spec.smartwear/u0a30 for activity com.spec.smartwear/.view.MainActivity
08-21 11:57:51.103    1230-1245/? V/WindowManager? Adding window Window{ffc1031 u0 com.spec.smartwear/com.spec.smartwear.view.MainActivity} at 2 of 3 (after Window{34d11084 u0 com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home.HomeActivity})
08-21 11:57:52.347    1230-1255/? I/ActivityManager? Displayed com.spec.smartwear/.view.MainActivity: +1s616ms
```

**wear app gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.spec.smartwear"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0.7"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

**phone app gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.spec.smartwear"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0.7"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.0.5'
    wearApp project(':wearable')
    compile 'org.scribe:scribe:1.3.5'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/FlurryAnalytics-4.1.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the version of the wear app?

Comment: Yes, I have changed version too but it is not working @greywolf82

Comment: Maybe the wear app is not updated because the previous version is signed with a different key for example the debug one.

Comment: Try to bump the versions for both the phone and wear app, connect adb to your watch and monitor logs (adb logcat) and while doing that update your phone app; there should be something in the logs on the wear regarding the updating the wear app (or a failure with some message) that can hopefully point to the issue.

Comment: @greywolf82 No dear older version is also signed one.

Comment: @ali I have tried this one also but not working

Comment: I didn't ask for whether it works or not, I was looking for logs. There is nothing anyone can do to help you unless you provide more information; right now the only suggestion (bumping the version number) didn't seem to do any good, so unless there is log or more info from your side, I don't think you can get more help.

Comment: Thank you ali! I have also checked all logs. Everything is fine no negative message. After that I posted here.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Hi I have added logging information in question while installing app. Please look into this and suggest which things are going wrong? I have tried another different ways like creating new project, cleaning project and rebuilding project but nothing works. Help me out.

Comment: @AliNaddaf I have also added Gradle information too

Comment: @UmangKothari Did you find any solution? I have same problem now!

Comment: @AVEbrahimi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772847/android-wear-embedding-old-cached-wear-apk-in-the-mobile-release-apk/26418273#26418273 This answer may help you.